# How to share value between 2 war files?

Tags: java

How to share value (LogIn User Name) between mutiple war files. These 2 war files are doployed both on JBoss and Weblogic.

Comment: you mean share value between two web application ? if so, update your question. someone devoted without comment

Comment: What to share? Login informations (in database), sessions, variables!?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are both webserver in the same domain? etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sharing a configuration value, there are several ways: the simplest would be a file that both systems can reach via the file-system, or a database.

If you are sharing active state (e.g. web sessions) between the two systems you could use a database or a [shared cache](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions).

Alternatively, you could have the two systems communicate with each other via some kind of API (e.g. via HTTP calls).

Comment: Menu.properties i have used the below code to trigger my LoginServlet, which will try to load it DashBoard page 

mnuCashManegement.ParentId=ROOT
mnuCashManegement1.ParentId=mnuCashManegement
mnuCashManegement1.URL=/CMS/cmsLoginServlet

in the LoginServlet the session is not getting the log in user name

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're saying, but it seems like there could be all kinds of possibilities as to what's wrong. It's going to be very difficult to diagnose the problem without a lot more information. I think you're are going to have do some debugging (follow the code through, try to simplify the situation and eliminate as many possibilities as you can) so you can narrow in on the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Webservice](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/) we can easily communicate.